# Size is Larger than MaxDocumentSize

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Using the 10gen C# driver for MongoDB, every once in a while in production I'm seeing this error:

System.IO.FileFormatException: Size is larger than MaxDocumentSize at MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonBinaryReader.ReadSize() in C:\work\10gen\mongodb\mongo-csharp-driver\Bson\IO\BsonBinaryReader.cs:line 556

Is there a way to make the MaxDocumentSize larger to prevent this error?

There is no way my document sizes are anywhere near 16MB, nor am I storing any files. Here is a sample document, which looks to be 13KB when I save it in notepad.

```
{
  "Address": "1080 DUNLAP ORPHANAGE RD",
  "Baths": null,
  "Beds": null,
  "Broker": "Crye-Leike, Inc., REALTORS |(901)840-1181",
  "City": "Unincorporated",
  "Coordinates": {
    "Latitude": 35.414949,
    "Longitude": -89.676481
  },
  "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:11 GMT -04:00",
  "Description": "",
  "ExteriorConstruction": "Aluminum/Steel Siding, Double Pane Window(s), Vinyl Siding, Conventional Foundation",
  "ExteriorFeatures": "",
  "FireplaceFeatures": "In Den/Great Room, Masonry, Wood Stove Insert",
  "HasGarage": true,
  "HeatingFeatures": "Ceiling Heat, Central, Gas, Wood Stove",
  "HouseSize": null,
  "InteriorFeatures": "Double Vanity Bath, Split Bedroom Plan, BEDROOM 2: Carpet, Level 2, Walk-In Closet; BEDROOM 3: Carpet, Level 2, Walk-In Closet; BEDROOM 4: Carpet, Level 2, Private Half Bath, Walk-In Closet; Part Carpet, Part Hardwood, Sprayed Ceiling, Tile Floor, Wood Laminate Floors, Attic Access, Cable Available, Cable Wired, Central Vac, Mud Room, Walk-In Attic, Walk-In Closet(s), Breakfast Bar, Eat-In Kitchen, Pantry, Separate Dining Room, Washer/Dryer Connections, MASTER BATH: Carpet, Double Sinks, Dressing Area, Tile Floor; Gas Water Heater, Entry Hall",
  "IsActive": true,
  "ListingFeatures": [
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "Status: ACTIVE"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "County: Tipton"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "Approximately 10 acre(s)"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "2 total full bath(s)"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "2 total half bath(s)"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "9 total rooms"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "2 stories"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "Type:  General Residential"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "Master Bedroom is Carpet, Full Bath, Level 1, Walk-In Closet"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "Basement is Partial, Unfinished"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "Pool features:  Above Ground"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "2 covered parking space(s)"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "Yes car garage(s)"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "Attached parking"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "Cooling features:  220 Wiring, Dual System,Cooling"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "Inclusions:  Cooktop, Dishwasher, Gas Cooking, Microwave, Refrigerator, Satellite Dish, Self Cleaning Oven"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "Lot features:  Chain Fenced, Landscaped, Level, Some Trees, Wooded"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "Lot size is between 10 and 20 acres"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "Utilities present:  Public Water, Septic Tank"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "Swimming pool(s)"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "Basement"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "Den"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "Laundry room"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "Hardwood floors"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "Name": "Parking features:  Driveway/Pad, Garage Door Opener(s), Storage Room(s), Workshop(s)"
    }
  ],
  "ListingPhotos": [
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "OriginalPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v01/l7d100943-m0x.jpg",
      "OriginalPhoto": null,
      "OriginalPhotoUpdateDate": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v01/l7d100943-m0t.jpg",
      "ThumbnailPhoto": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUpdateDate": null
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "OriginalPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v01/l7d100943-m1x.jpg",
      "OriginalPhoto": null,
      "OriginalPhotoUpdateDate": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v01/l7d100943-m1t.jpg",
      "ThumbnailPhoto": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUpdateDate": null
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "OriginalPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v01/l7d100943-m2x.jpg",
      "OriginalPhoto": null,
      "OriginalPhotoUpdateDate": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v01/l7d100943-m2t.jpg",
      "ThumbnailPhoto": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUpdateDate": null
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "OriginalPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v01/l7d100943-m3x.jpg",
      "OriginalPhoto": null,
      "OriginalPhotoUpdateDate": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v01/l7d100943-m3t.jpg",
      "ThumbnailPhoto": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUpdateDate": null
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "OriginalPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v01/l7d100943-m4x.jpg",
      "OriginalPhoto": null,
      "OriginalPhotoUpdateDate": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v01/l7d100943-m4t.jpg",
      "ThumbnailPhoto": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUpdateDate": null
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "OriginalPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v01/l7d100943-m5x.jpg",
      "OriginalPhoto": null,
      "OriginalPhotoUpdateDate": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v01/l7d100943-m5t.jpg",
      "ThumbnailPhoto": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUpdateDate": null
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "OriginalPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v01/l7d100943-m6x.jpg",
      "OriginalPhoto": null,
      "OriginalPhotoUpdateDate": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v01/l7d100943-m6t.jpg",
      "ThumbnailPhoto": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUpdateDate": null
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "OriginalPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v02/l7d100943-m7x.jpg",
      "OriginalPhoto": null,
      "OriginalPhotoUpdateDate": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v02/l7d100943-m7t.jpg",
      "ThumbnailPhoto": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUpdateDate": null
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "OriginalPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v02/l7d100943-m8x.jpg",
      "OriginalPhoto": null,
      "OriginalPhotoUpdateDate": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v02/l7d100943-m8t.jpg",
      "ThumbnailPhoto": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUpdateDate": null
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "OriginalPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v02/l7d100943-m9x.jpg",
      "OriginalPhoto": null,
      "OriginalPhotoUpdateDate": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v02/l7d100943-m9t.jpg",
      "ThumbnailPhoto": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUpdateDate": null
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "OriginalPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v02/l7d100943-m10x.jpg",
      "OriginalPhoto": null,
      "OriginalPhotoUpdateDate": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v02/l7d100943-m10t.jpg",
      "ThumbnailPhoto": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUpdateDate": null
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "CreateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:04 GMT -04:00",
      "OriginalPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v01/l7d100943-m11x.jpg",
      "OriginalPhoto": null,
      "OriginalPhotoUpdateDate": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUrl": "http://p.rdcpix.com/v01/l7d100943-m11t.jpg",
      "ThumbnailPhoto": null,
      "ThumbnailPhotoUpdateDate": null
    }
  ],
  "ListingPriceHistories": null,
  "ListingSalesHistories": [],
  "ListingTaxHistories": [],
  "LotSize": null,
  "MlsCreateDate": "Sat, 15 Jan 2011 19:40:04 GMT -05:00",
  "MlsId": "3215435",
  "MlsRefreshDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:31:04 GMT -04:00",
  "Neighborhood": "Not Available",
  "Price": 290000,
  "PropertyType": "Single Family Home",
  "RealtorUrl": "http://realtor.com/realestateandhomes-detail/1080-dunlap-orphanage-rd_unincorporated_tn_38011_1124667517",
  "Roofing": "Composition Shingles",
  "State": "TN",
  "Stories": 2,
  "Style": "Traditional",
  "UpdateDate": "Sun, 03 Apr 2011 19:40:11 GMT -04:00",
  "YearBuilt": 1987,
  "ZipCode": "38011",
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "4d99055b1b9ba917bcef9443"
  }
}
```

Comment: The limit is 16GB in MongoDB 1.8. What are you storing that large? Can't you use GridFS?

Comment: I'm not storing anything close to 16MB.

Comment: you don't happen to be creating that document on some sort of loop do you?  I did that and I accidentally forget to start over on each loop iteration so I got a really large file and receive the same exact error.

Comment: @atbebtg - Could you describe further what you mean by you created it on a loop and forgot to start over? I'm simply using Collection.Save() and passing in my object. Thanks.

Comment: I had a class with List<Foo> as one of the property.  I was converting few thousands of record form sql to mongodb so I was looping through recordset to create a new instance of the class and then doing an inner loop to get the List<Foo>.  I forgot to clear the List<Foo> on each outer loop iteration so by the time I reached the 1000th iteration the List<Foo> was soo large that I received the Size is Larger than MaxDocumentSize error.  I just thought I'll throw it out there because it took me a while before I realized that.  I was stuck on my doc size is small so that can't be it mentality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally if your documents were too large you would expect to get this error when writing them to the database, not when reading them back.

Can you provide some more information:

- which version of the C# driver are you using?
- which version of the server are you using?
- do you know the size of the document that is causing this?
- can you successfully retrieve this document using the mongo shell or another driver?

If you are willing to build the driver yourself you could set a breakpoint on the line that is throwing the exception and determine the size of the document and the max document size and report those numbers back.

Thanks.

Comment: "Normally if your documents were too large you would expect to get this error when writing them to the database, not when reading them back." <-- I think you're on to something here, as my documents aren't that big.

Comment: I'm using version 1.0.0.4098 of the C# driver. It says MongoDB shell version: 1.6.5, not sure if that's the server version or just the shell. The documents all range around 20KB or less, and it's unpredictable, sometimes a document will return fine, then another time it'll throw this error. I haven't tried retrieving the document using the shell, I'll try that when I get a chance.

Comment: So it doesn't look like your documents should ever get near the maximum size (which was 4MB back in 1.6, and is currently 16MB). Another reason I have seen this error is corrupt data, which causes a length field to have a weird value which often exceeds the maximum document size. But I've also seen this error when there was bug in the BSON reader code and it lost its position (though I haven't seen that in a long time...). If you find a way to reproduce this consistently let me know.

Comment: I actually have a production url that reproduces it every time, I'm copying the production database down locally then I should be able to reproduce it while debugging. Would a repairDatabase() command fix the corrupt data issue? I could try a repair as well as upgrading my server version to the latest, however I guess even if it increased to 16MB then it's still worrisome that my >20KB of data is registering as over 4MB.

Comment: I upgraded to mongo 1.8.2-rc2 and the error went away, thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear the problem went away with the latest version. Thanks for letting us know!

Comment: @RobertStam, I agree with that. I have seen this error is corrupt data or duplicate data, which the BSON object store the corrupt data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to adjust and recompile the source of MongoDb. I haven't tried this but I found this: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/29d9dab034c6f7df497b76f543ba467e687a9063

Edit 1: OP has provided additional info that makes my answer no longer relevant.